# Regular expression which matches a domain with only two ending characters?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to stop spammers who are using short domains bit.ly etc. The domains they post seem to all be only two characters (not .com, etc). 
I've used this:

```
\.[a-z][a-z]$
```

But, it has two problems:
it matches .co.uk
If anything is after the domain, it doesn't match (a space or slash, example: bit.ly/2231)

Could someone assist me with a regex that would accomplish this, please?

Comment: that doesn't seem like a very reliable way to do it.  maybe use this list instead? http://www.surbl.org/tld

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whole URL matching.  Depends on domain being before the first forward slash past protocol.  First one uses if it only has one dot in the url and ends with two character primary TLD.  Second one uses negative lookbehind to make sure it's not something like .co.uk.

https://regex101.com/r/5acu56/2

```
^(https?:\/\/)?[^\/.]+\.[a-z][a-z](\/|\s*$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/p8Ajw9/2

```
^(https?:\/\/)?[^\/]+(?<!\.[a-z][a-z])\.[a-z][a-z](\/\s*|\s*$)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would this work for http as well?

Comment: Yes, the `s?` makes the s optional.  Use the regex101.com link.  It drills down all the matches on the upper right, so you can see what it's doing in real time with detailed explanation.  You can also paste a bunch of test strings or create unit tests.

Comment: When I used the regex101 link and tested them out and added a space after the domain it no longer matched. Not sure how exactly to send you to show that?

Comment: So something like trim()?  I've added whitespace inclusion